# asp.net core maproute template with string concatenate to action

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a HelloController
When i input URL with http://localhost/Hello/1234

How Could i link to the W1234

I try to modify maproute template like
template: {controller}/W{action}

But it didn't work

```cs
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
       routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Hello",
         template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    });


    public partial class HelloController : Controller
    {
       public IActionResult W1234()
       {
          return View();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Attribute routing` uses a set of attributes to map actions directly to route templates.

```
[[Route("Hello/1234")]
public IActionResult W1234()
{
    return View();
}
```

Attribute routing can also make use of the `Http[Verb]` attributes such as `HttpPostAttribute`. All of these attributes can accept a route template.

```
[HttpGet("/Hello/1234")]
public IActionResult W1234()
{
    return View();
}
```

Reference : [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: But i have action 1000~9999,if i use attribute routing,i will write thousand times attribute